# How to redirect Oauth2 request to the application web browser

Tags: c#, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using OAUTH2 in Gmail authentication. Its working fine. But Google apis redirect the authentication request to default web browser on the machine. I have added web browser control in my application and want to redirect the authentication request in it. How can I achieve it?

```
    userCredentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecret,
                                                                  scopes,
                                                                  Username,
                                                                  System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                                                                  objFileDataStore).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the Google .net client library.   At this time the Google .net client library does not support launching the authentication window in a web browser control.   It will always launch the default web browser.

There was a pull request to add this functionality to the library but Google declined to add it to the library.  [Add option to use Winforms embedded browser #547](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/pull/665)